# Deployment of Angular.js app

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment, karma-runner

When deploying Angular.js app to production server, should I remove Karma test folder and its dependencies for webfarm? For this app the structure is:

```
/app
 /css
 /js
 /img
 /lib
   /angular
 /partials
 index.html
/config
/logs
/test
```

/scripts

Should I just copy the content of app folder to webfarm and post that on server?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production, yes, you should **not** publish the `/test` folder. Tests are for you and your development team, not for your end users.